# Python ctypes winapi GetUserProfileDirectory access violation reading

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to get a new users profile path after logging them in for the first time, yet I am getting an "OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x********"

I call ctypes.windll.advapi32.LogonUserW() and pass the token and a PROFILEINFOW structure to ctypes.windll.userenv.LoadUserProfileW()

The users profile gets created, yet if a folder names after the username already exists then windows automatically makes a new folder.

The profile path inside the PROFILEINFOW structure is None, so I want to call ctypes.windll.userenv.GetUserProfileDirectoryW(). If I pass in a buffer size of zero, then I get a response back with the buffer indicating the required size, yet even with a buffer = MAX_PATH I am still getting the reading violation

```
token = ctypes.c_void_p()
ctypes.windll.advapi32.LogonUserW(username, domain, password, 2, 0, ctypes.byref(token))

class PROFILEINFOW(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('Size', ctypes.c_ulong),
                ('Flags', ctypes.c_ulong),
                ('UserName', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('ProfilePath', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('DefaultPath', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('ServerName', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('PolicyPath', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('Handle', ctypes.c_void_p)]

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.Size = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        self.UserName = username
        super().__init__()

profile = PROFILEINFOW(username)
ctypes.windll.userenv.LoadUserProfileW(token, ctypes.byref(profile))
```

This works:

```
profile_directory_buffer = ctypes.c_ulong()
ctypes.windll.userenv.GetUserProfileDirectoryW(token, None, ctypes.byref(profile_directory_buffer))
```

The following all fail with reading violation error:

```
profile_directory = ctypes.c_wchar_p()
ctypes.windll.userenv.GetUserProfileDirectoryW(token, ctypes.byref(profile_directory), 260)

profile_directory = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(260)
ctypes.windll.userenv.GetUserProfileDirectoryW(token, profile_directory, 260)

profile_directory = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(260)
ctypes.windll.userenv.GetUserProfileDirectoryW(token, ctypes.byref(profile_directory), 260)
```

The first 2 commands run without issue, yet I can figure out the syntax on the 3rd command to get around this violation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess it depends on the function, but in this case I was able to get the path by doing the following:

```
profile_directory = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(260)
profile_buffer = ctypes.c_ulong(260)
ctypes.windll.userenv.GetUserProfileDirectoryW(self.token, ctypes.byref(profile_directory), ctypes.byref(profile_buffer))
```